# Wrong rectangle position in responsive canvas

Tags: html, responsive-design, fabricjs

When I click at two positions on the canvas rectangle, it gets drawn but I got the wrong position of the rectangle for responsive canvas size. I have tried to scale the pointer position with the canvas and the window width but I am still facing some problem.

```
<html lang="en" >

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Demo</title>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.1.0/fabric.all.min.js" ></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<style>

</style>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="panel" width="700" height="400"></canvas>   
    </div>

</div>
</body>
<script>
    (function() {
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('panel');
        var clicks=0;
        var count=0;
        var x1=0;var y1=0;
        var rect;
        // handle responsively resizing the canvas   
        var scale=1.00;
        var originalWindowWidth=window.innerWidth;
        var originalCanvasWidth=document.getElementById('panel').width;

        console.log("originalWindowWidth:"+originalWindowWidth+",originalCanvasWidth :"+originalCanvasWidth);

        scale=window.innerWidth/originalCanvasWidth;
        console.log("scale : "+scale);
        $('#panel').css('width',originalCanvasWidth*scale);
        canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e){
         //check if you clicked on an object that exists canvas\

            if(e.target == undefined){

                    if (clicks == 0) {
                        var pointer=canvas.getPointer(event.e);
                        console.log(pointer);
                        x1 = pointer.x;
                        y1 =pointer.y;
                        console.log("Start Pointer " +x1 ,y1);
                        clicks++;
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        var endpointer=canvas.getPointer();
                        console.log(endpointer);
                        var endx=endpointer.x;
                        var endy=endpointer.y;
                        console.log("Endpointer  " +endx ,endy);
                        console.log("x and y"+x1,y1);
                        var newwidth=(endpointer.x- x1)/scale;
                        var newheight=(endpointer.y - y1)/scale;

                        rect=new fabric.Rect({
                                left:x1,
                                top: y1,
                                originX :'left',
                                originY :'top',

                                width:newwidth,
                                height:newheight,
                                selectable: true,
                                evented:false,
                                fill:'red',
                                opacity :0.3

                            });
                        canvas.add(rect);
                        //console.log(rect.setWidth(pointer2.x- x1 ));
                        //console.log(rect.setHeight( pointer2.y - y1));
                        canvas.renderAll();
                        clicks=0;   
                        count++;
                        console.log(count);
                    }   
                }
                else
                {
                    //console.log("123");
                    //canvas.__eventListeners["mouse:down"] = [];
                }
            });

            canvas.on('object:moving',function(){
                var bound=rect.getBoundingRect();
                console.log(bound.left,bound.top,bound.width,bound.height);
            });
            canvas.on('object:scaling',function(){
                var bound=rect.getBoundingRect();
                console.log(bound.left,bound.top,bound.width,bound.height);
            });
            canvas.on('object:selected',function(e){
                //canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
                document.onkeydown = function(e) {

                      if (e.keyCode === 27||e.button==2) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                        canvas.getActiveObject().remove();
                    }

                }

            });
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var pwidth = $("#panel").parent().parent().width();
                var pheight = $("#panel").parent().parent().height();
                console.log("pwidth:" + pwidth + ",pheight" + pheight);

                $(".lower-canvas").css("width", pwidth);
                $(".lower-canvas").css("height", 'auto');
               // $(".lower-canvas").css("padding-left",-23);

                $("#panel").css("height", 'auto');
                var panelheight=$("#panel").height();
                var panelwidth = $("#panel").width();
               console.log("panelheight" + panelheight);
               $(".canvas-container").css("height", panelheight);
               $(".canvas-container").css("width", panelwidth);


            });
            $(window).resize(function () {
                var pwidth = $("#panel").parent().parent().width();
                var pheight = $("#panel").parent().parent().height();
                console.log("pwidth:" + pwidth + ",pheight" + pheight);
                // canvas.width = width;
                $(".lower-canvas").css("width", pwidth);
                $(".lower-canvas").css("height", 'auto');

                $("#panel").css("height", 'auto');
                var panelheight = $("#panel").height();
                var panelwidth = $("#panel").width();
                console.log("panelheight" + panelheight);
                $(".canvas-container").css("height", panelheight);
                $(".canvas-container").css("width", panelwidth);
            });
            fabric.Image.fromURL('fedex.jpg', function (img) {
                canvas.add(img.set({
                    width: canvas.width,
                    height: canvas.height,
                    originX: 'left',
                    originY: 'top',
                    selectable: false,

                }));
            });
    })();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made from your code a fiddle.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/3j81t254/1/

The problem is that you are not updating scale on windows resize and that you should not scale width and height with scale factor but both the cursor positions in the click event.

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  var pwidth = $("#panel").parent().parent().width();
  var pheight = $("#panel").parent().parent().height();
  // canvas.width = width;
  $(".lower-canvas").css("width", pwidth);
  $(".lower-canvas").css("height", 'auto');

  $("#panel").css("height", 'auto');
  var panelheight = $("#panel").height();
  var panelwidth = $("#panel").width();
  //update scale factor
  scale = pwidth/ 700;
  $(".canvas-container").css("height", panelheight);
  $(".canvas-container").css("width", panelwidth);
});



    if (clicks == 0) {
      var pointer = canvas.getPointer(event.e);
      //scale this
      x1 = pointer.x / scale;
      y1 = pointer.y / scale;
      console.log("Start Pointer " + x1, y1);
      clicks++;
    } else {
      var endpointer = canvas.getPointer();
      //scale this
      var endx = endpointer.x / scale;
      var endy = endpointer.y / scale;
      console.log("Endpointer  " + endx, endy);
      console.log("x and y" + x1, y1);
      var newwidth = (endx - x1);
      var newheight = (endy - y1);
   }
```

Using the canvas in a responsive environment is not yet supporte with fabricjs, there are a lot of problems here and there.
good luck